# Regarding apt-cache search -n on iPhone

Tags: apt, apt-cache

I try to search certain package using *`apt-cache search -n iap cracker`*, but some list from `/var/lib/apt/lists` it's not appear.

Example:

```
Ojek:~ root# apt-cache search -n iap cracker
com.ihacksrepo.iapcracker - Free inapp purchases
com.repocydia.iapcrackerlist - A List for The apps/Games that work with iAp Cracker
com.xsellize.iapcrackerlist - A List for The apps/Games that work with iAp Cracker
com.sinfuliphone.iapcracker - Allows you to get FREE In-App Purchases!
```

One of the repo list that not appear in search output:

```
Package: com.duowan.urus.iap
Version: 0.8-1
Architecture: iphoneos-arm
Installed-Size: 132
Maintainer: duowan
Depends: mobilesubstrate
Section: [å¤^Úç^Î© - è½¯ä»¶]
Icon: file:///Applications/Cydia.app/Sections/Utilities.png
Priority: standard
Homepage: http://iphone.duowan.com/
Depiction: http://iphone.duowan.com/1109/179506764380.html
Description: è®©ä½ ç^Ú^Ä App å^Å^Íè´¹ä¸^Ëè½½å^Æ^Åç½®ä»^Øè´¹å^Æ^Åå®¹å^Ï^ÊDLCå^Æ^$
Sponsor: Duowan.com <http://iphone.duowan.com/m/>
Name: iAP Cracker
Filename: debs/com.duowan.urus.iap_0.8-1_iphoneos-arm.deb
Size: 56752
MD5sum: 46e4837d42a287e1411a468f22e0489a
```

How to ensure I able to get output every name im searching? Sorry for my english.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question regarding Ubuntu Desktop. If it is related to Ubuntu for android/phone/tablet state that in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I add iPhone on the tittle, thank you for the info